Remove Space Between Header and First Block
I am making a online booking website with WooCommerce Booking and the Storefront Theme.
On my home page I made a banner with an image and a button as seen in the image below.
However,  I have not been able to get rid of that white space.
I have added the following code in the custom CCS section of wordpress to remove the title
Any idea how I can remove the space? I want the banner and the header to be touching
My code:
.page .entry-title {
display: none;
}

Here is the link to the website: https://idm.beb.mybluehost.me/


can you share the website? or a minimal code to make some tests?

@Syntax_Error I have added the link to the website to the question

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

But it's this home.blog .site-header, .home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header, .home.post-type-archive-product .site-header {     margin-bottom: 4.235801032em; }

@Paulie_D thank you I'll make sure to do that next time

If you mean the white space above the banner.
Decrease the margin-bottom of this classes
.home.blog .site-header, .home.page:not(.page-template-template-homepage) .site-header, .home.post-type-archive-product .site-header {
  margin-bottom: 4.235801032em;
}

This is how it looks after that.

